# Adding web service reference to ASP.NET Website?

Tags: asp.net, webservice-client

I want to add a service reference to a wsdl web service in my ASP.NET website. In Visual Studio I right clicked the project and then Add service reference. It then created the *App_WebReferences* folder with some files in it and it added some new things to my web.config.

After I moved the changes to my test server by copying the new file, the App_WebReferences folder and the changed web.config, the server tells me that I'm missing a reference for the web service. I thought it should be in either web.config or that ASP.NET should find it in the App_WebReferences folder.

I've missed something obvious but I can't figure out what. What have I missed and what do I do to get my web service reference to work on my test server?

It's working really well on my local machine.

Comment: Did you update the project file?

Comment: Does a website have a project file? If so, where is it usually located?

Answer (score 0):

Was this working fine locally?  You need to make sure you import the service to any classes that may be using it (or Using if you are doing this in C#).  Also, is the service you imported from a project that is on your pc?  IF so, you will need publish that as well to the test server.